# If $X$ is uniformly $(0,1)$ distributed, how are we sure that $\log X$ is well defined?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, almost-everywhere

My book says that if $X$ is uniformly (0,1) distributed, then $-\log(X)$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $1$.

However, how are we sure that $- \log(X)$ is well defined?

I.e., can't it be the case that $X$ takes negative values?

Comment: You said so yourself that X is uniformly distributed on (0, 1)...thus it only takes values between that (positive) range

Comment: We defined a uniform distribution as an absolutely continuous distribution with density function $f$ defined by $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in (0,1)$ and $0$ elsewhere. How does it follow from this that $X$ only attains values between $(0,1)$?

Comment: The density function you just mentioned shows that the probability of X giving an output that is NOT in (0, 1) is 0...so X gives values in the range (0, 1)

Comment: I can see that $P(X \leq 0) = 0$. But how does it follow that $ \{X \leq 0\} = \emptyset$?

Comment: You are facing a most useful convention in probability theory, which is that almost surely equal random variables are identified. In your case, consider $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)=((0,1),\mathcal B((0,1)),\mathrm{Leb})$ and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ defined by $X(\omega)=\omega$. Then $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ and $\log X$ is defined everywhere on $\Omega$. Next, define $Y(\omega)=\omega$ if $\omega$ is irrational and $Y(\omega)=-1$ if $\omega$ is rational. ...

Comment: ... Then $\log Y(\omega)$ does not exist if $\omega$ is in $B\in\mathcal B((0,1))$ with $P(B)=0$ but the distribution of $Y$ is also uniform on $(0,1)$ hence we can (and we do) identify $Y$ to $X$.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't study formal measure theory yet, but I understand what you are saying. Thanks.

Comment: @Did Reading this answer after having studied measure theory gave a lot of insight! You can make it an answer to the question so I can upvote and accept.